# Can’t add clock to world clock widget in El Capitan

Tags: macos, notifications, bug, widgets

Whenever I try to add a clock to the World Clock widget in the Today area of Notification Center, it never gets added. Sometimes I can’t even search for the city I want to add. However, whenever I am able to search for a city, it finds it, and when I press enter or click on the name, it behaves as it should be, but the clock never gets displayed.

[image]

And yet it remains like this:

[image]

What I tried so far:

- restart Finder;
- restart computer;
- delete the widget and add it back.

Comment: Have you tried to restart the system?

Comment: @Mattia, yes, I did and nothing changed.

Comment: Try deleting the widget and adding it again

Comment: @user2277872, done that as well — no luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is you need to click the (i) ("Info") button in the upper right of the widget before you click on the "Add" button.

If not an explicit bug, this is certainly a major usability issue, but only is an issue when adding the first clock (otherwise the "Add" button doesn't show up until you press Info). I had run into this as well and couldn't figure it out for months. Finally poked around at it more just now and finally figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried this. Did you click the name of the city that came up? If so, it should add without issue. If that doesn't work, relaunch Finder and try again.

Comment: Already tried. I also tried restarting the whole system.